# simple notification email template

Tags: html, css, email, templates, notifications

If you do a search on Google there are millions of newsletter email templates, all I am looking for is something that is purposed for a single notification. I don't really want to learn HTML all over again just to produce this so any links or articles would help TONSSS!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily get something going using an email boilerplate such as this one as base:

http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/